# Functional way of finding inverse ranges

Tags: javascript, regex, functional-programming, templating

I'm writing a templating utility for a library and trying to do it in a functional way (no mutable variables and ideally no intermediate state). **This is mainly a learning exercise and I know there are libraries out there that do this already.**

Given the string:

```
"Hello, {{name}}! What are you doing on {{day}}?"`
```

I have matched the template tags against a Regex, which combined with a range finding function will return the tagged matches as 'range' objects.

```
[
  { start: 7, end: 14 },
  { start: 39, end: 45 }
]
```

I want to define the entire string as ranges, so that I can compile the ranges into a list of functions.

```
[
  { start: 0, end: 6 }
  { start: 7, end: 14, tag: true },
  { start: 15: end: 38 }
  { start: 39, end: 45, tag: true },
  { start: 46, end: 46 }
]
```

Tagging them isn't an issue, but finding the other ranges is. This task can obviously be done with a for loop and some counter variables, but you will be mutating state. `for`, `forEach` and `while` are out of the question.

How would you go about getting this done without mutating state? Would it be possible to get all of the ranges in one pass (rather than using regex then a second pass to find the inverse ranges)?

Ultimately, I will end up with a list of bound functions that look something like this:

```
[
  text('Hello, '),
  lookup('name'),
  text('! What are you doing on '),
  lookup('day'),
  text('?')
]
```

Calling these will result in a series of lookups which will return string values and the text functions are just bound identity functions which will return their argument.

Comment: I understand that it is a learning exercise but is there a particular reason to get the positions of substrings?

Comment: Not if it can be done otherwise. My intention was to keep track of the substring indexes in order to slice them out later to build the in-place templating functions from later.

Comment: The `replace` method is very flexible since it can take a callback function as replacement parameter and to work with it you don't need to know what are the indexes.

Comment: **Warning! Not recommended** `"Hello, {{name}}! What are you doing on {{day}}?".match(/\{\{\w+}}|.+?(?=\{\{\w+}}|$)/g)`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I see what you're saying, but the desired end result will be a list of functions and using replace doesn't get me any closer to that.

Comment: I was thinking about something like this: https://eval.in/357793 (without a step where you build a list of functions)

Comment: Ah, I see. That would work, but I was hoping to only deal with strings at the start of runtime, in order to have a compiled version of the template ready, that could be evaluated with no string manipulation needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would it be possible to get all of the ranges in one pass?

Yes - as you can use a regex with a capturing group to [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) your input string:

```
var tag = /(\{\{.+?\}\})/;
var parts = str.split(tag);
```

and then you can directly [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) those to your functions:

```
var res = parts.map(function(part) {
    return tag.test(part) ? lookup(part.slice(2, -2)) : text(part);
});
```

No ranges needed at all :-)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your string is properly formatted (balanced non-nested `{{` and `}}`), you can do it as simply as:

```
s.split(/{{|}}/g).map(function (t, i) {
    return i % 2 ? lookup(t) : text(t);
});
```

One surprising thing may be that when you start/end the string with a tag, it starts/ends the array with text(''). This, however, is why it can be done so simply.

Comment: You mean `/\{\{|\}\}/g`

Answer (score 1):

Since you want "a list of bound functions", here is one way to do it.

```
function lookup() {
  return this.toUpperCase();
}
function text() {
  return this.toString();
}

function parse(input) {
    return input.split(/(?=\{\{)|\}\}/g).map(function (part) {
        var isPlaceholder = part.slice(0, 2) === '{{',
            txt = isPlaceholder ? part.slice(2) : part;
        return (isPlaceholder ? lookup : text).bind(txt);
    });
}

function materialize(parts) {
    return parts.map(function(f) { return f(); }).join("");
}

materialize(parse("Hello, {{name}}! What are you doing on {{day}}?"));
// -> "Hello, NAME! What are you doing on DAY?"
```